# How can I make a div element both scrollable and draggable for the inner content?

Tags: jquery, css, draggable, scrollable

I'm running into the issue where I have a game board laid out on the web page. If this game board is 20x20 squares and the container for it can only fit 10x10, I need the game board inside to be draggable. The user should not be able to drag it outside of the bounds of the container (as in the 0,0 tile shouldn't pass the top left of the container, and the 19,19 tile shouldn't go above or the left o the bottom right of the container).

jQuery UI has a draggable element that allows me to drag it, but the only constraints I can seem to make are purely related to the container itself. I got around this by setting bounds (using the [x1, y1, x2, y2] format instead of a container) and that worked for a while--except the dragging is slow and does not work well with a scrollable solution.

My issues with a scrollable field (without the drag) put the scrollbars inside the content and just looks very messy.

Is there a good draggable solution that has inertial scroll to the element? Is scrolling the only way to go? Am I really limited to toggling between one or the other?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have tried using the css element "scroll: auto" ?

Comment: Yes. Maybe I didn't explain clearly enough in my answer, but I'm looking for a solution that is both draggable *and* scrollable--not something that triggers depending on size. The issue with the scroll attribute is that scroll and drag don't work properly together using jQuery UI.